# How to deserialize ROS messages from Bag to ROS defined types in C++?

Tags: ros, c++, rosbag

I want to deserialize messages from a Bag file and publishing part of their contents with ROS for further processing.

I read a bagfile with the ROS C++ API. I know exactly the content (topic names and types) of my messages at compile time, such that I want to deserialize it into common ROS defined classes (e.g. the ones defined here https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/index-msg.html) at runtime.
Here some code:

```
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>
//other content
  rosbag::Bag bag;
  bag.open("foo.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Read);

  std::vector<std::string> topics{"camera1/camera_info"};

  rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));

  for(auto const m : view)
  {
      const std::string& topic_name = m.getTopic();
      std::cout << topic_name << std::endl;
      std_msgs::String::ConstPtr s = m.instantiate<std_msgs::String>();
      if (s != NULL)
          std::cout << s->data << std::endl;
 
      // I want the data in s as a string to be serialized into an instance
      // of the type CameraInfo located in 
      // path/ros/distro/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h shipping with ROS.
      CameraInfo ci = is_there_any_os_solution(s); //?
  }

  bag.close();
```

I tried to find something on this direction but I just found libraries deserializing contents unknown at compile time.

Could anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're looking for the [`instantiate` method](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1MessageInstance.html#a369b32708a1a8bdaad133a47152a4885) on the rosbag `MessageInstance`

There's a very minimal example [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/)

```
BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
{
    std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr i = m.instantiate<std_msgs::Int32>();
...
```

And more examples [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) and a [cookbook of examples using the rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook).

Comment: Thanks! I do not know how safe this is but I tried with more complex types like CameraInfo in sensor_msgs and it really works! I thought this was only working with primitive types but how wrong I was.